# How to avoid the prompting for user name and passwords when anonymous user click an item in Lists?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

As the title shows, I faced an issue in lists. What I need is when an anonymous user clicks an item in the list to view it, I want them to be able to view the item and not to be asked to enter user name and password.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution , 
I did the steps given below :

- Click Start, click Run, type cmd in the Open box, and then click OK.
- Type the following lines at the command prompt. Press ENTER after each line.
  cd /d %commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\Bin stsadm -o
  deactivatefeature -url http:// (your site name) -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
- Type exit to exit the command prompt.
- you must turn anonymous access off and on again for changes to take effect ,by enabling and 
  disabling anonymous access in your needed zone and then navigate to your list permission un 
  check view item permission from annonymous permission list and then click ok and the re open the 
  same permission list and check the view item permission box again .

for more details visit this link : http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2007/06/anonymous-users-cannot-access-list.html ( Many thanks for that post )

Thanks for all of you !

Comment: I would use caution in deactivating the ViewFormPagesLockDown feature. For an intranet site, it might be acceptable, but for an extranet or internet site, deactivating this feature will expose your form pages and many applications pages to everyone worldwide. In this case, you would be advised to create a custom page containing a list form web part.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable anonymous access on the list. Before you do this, you'll also need to enable anonymous access on the site.

You can find more information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/enable-anonymous-access-HA010113018.aspx) on how to do it.

Comment: Jose Thank you for your reply , but i did that and still if i try to click any item in the announcement list it ask me to enter user name and password , any idea !